# Media query failing for resolution under Internet Explorer 11 with respond.js included

Tags: css, media-queries, internet-explorer-11

I have the following code and am testing it on a square shaped 1280 x 1024 quare screen:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .m { height: 100px; width: 100px; background-color: aqua; }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
        .m { background-color: red; }
    }        
</style>

<div class="m"></div>
```

Everything works as expected in normal browsers, but on IE11 the div's colour is still aqua and not red. I have researched the issue and **included respond.js**, but it does not seem to make any difference. I have noticed that when I resize the browser window and make it just a little bit smaller the div gets indeed redm but not on full screen.

Update: here is a sample: http://codepen.io/vee6/pen/BoKGov

Comment: Do you have a viewport set? Can you put an example up somewhere so we can see it?

Comment: I edited and added a codepen sample. I didn't set any viewport as I am targeting desktop monitor. Should I use one?

Comment: If you want responsive rules, set a viewport. Respond.js is for IE 6-8 and entirely unnecessary in IE 11.

Comment: I tried using a viewport meta tag: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> or the css @-ms-viewport { width: device-width; }. No effect whatsoever.